# Filemaker 12 -- display one value, store another

Tags: filemaker

I'm building a database in FileMaker 12 that will, among other things, keep a list of jobs (indicated by numeric ID) and the employees who had billable time for that job.

Given three tables:

```
Employee ( empName, empID, salary, ... )
JobHours ( empID, jobID, hrsWorked, ... , refID)
JobCost  ( jobID, expenses, profit, ... , refID)
```

Where:

Employee is my personnel roster matching names to numeric employee IDs and stats (salary, et al) ;

JobHours is a list of employee participation -- whenever an employee spends time on a job, this table has a line that shows their ID, the job ID, hours worked, and a few other things;

JobCost is a daily record of jobs.  One entry in this table refers to the activity for a single job on a single day.  Additionally, each entry gets a system generated unique ID (since neither jobID nor date is unique) to relate to JobHours (resulting in a list of who worked on a particular job on a particular day).

I have a form showing records from JobCost.  For each record, I can see in a portal, showing records from JobHours, who worked on that job on that day.

Now, the issue.

In my portal, I want to have a drop-down list of employee names pulled from a value list to create records in JobHours with the following criteria:

1)  I need it to be a drop-down rather than a pop-up so it will respond to auto-fill from the keyboard.  A drop-down will show the secondary value (employee name) from a value list while dropped down, and will respond properly to keyboard autocomplete on the secondary value, but once you've made your selection, it only displays the primary value (employee ID).

2)  I need it to display names, not IDs, at all times.  The pop-up does this perfectly.  However, it doesn't seem to respond to the keyboard for typing autocompletes.

3)  I need to store the numeric ID rather than the name.

I know how to satisfy any two of these criteria at once, but that's all.  The whole database is working beautifully otherwise.  Is this behavior possible?

Comment: On my copy of FMPA 12 v3 (Mac) I am finding that both drop-down lists and pop-up menus can be typed in. Maybe check that your copy of FileMaker is up-to-date?

Comment: Just verified I'm up to date -- FMP 12.0v4 and no update is available when I check.  Could it be a difference between Pro and Advanced?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me, but it is possible. Maybe try getting a demo of Advanced from the website and see if that resolves the issue. Also try on a different computer--maybe some setting is corrupt on yours. Are you on a Mac or Windows?

Comment: I'm currently on Windows.  I did install my copy of Advanced on a separate machine with no apparent change in behavior.  I'll try Mac when I get a chance.  I wouldn't be surprised if that is the difference as these controls are typically a part of the OS rather than any specific application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common technique is to use two fields, one directly on top of the other.

On the bottom, put your JobHours::EmpID field. Set it up as the drop-down list with the value list that you've specified.

On top of the JobHours::EmpID field put the related Employee::EmpName field. Set the field so that it cannot be entered in browse or find mode.

Now your users will see the Employee Name, but when they click that click will go through the top field and into the Employee ID field where they will choose the name from the value list.

Comment: I did try this and as @Chuck mentions below it is somewhat inelegant. If I don't come up with anything else in the next day or so I'll probably go back to this and in that case mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

pft's solution is one that I have long used, but I do still find it inelegant because the user still sees an existing id number in the field when changing the value.

If the type-ahead is important, I would use the popup menu. Once the menu has been activated either by tabbing into it or by clicking into it, the user is able to type from the keyboard and the selection will change based on what's entered.

Comment: You and @pft221 agree that popups should respond to autocomplete.  Is there some toggle I could be missing?  It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Well, it's not *exactly* autocomplete, but when I created a quick test in FileMaker 12, with a static value list (Arizona, California, New York) and a field tied to it as a popup menu, I was able to click into the field to bring up the menu and type "C" to select California. So it isn't completing the contents so much as selecting the closest match.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread looking for a solution to this same issue (allowing the user to pick from a list, show their choice, but store a related value instead).  For example, choose a plant species name from a dropdown, show the plant species name in the dropdown field, but have it store the taxonomic serial number (TSN; which is more likely to stay the same over the years).  This is easy to do in MS Access, but took a litlte more messing around to do it in FMP12.

How I solved it:
I created two fields in the table that would be storing the values:  Plant_TSN and Plant_SciName.  A relationship must exist between the values in these two fields.  In my case, I store a SciName for each TSN in a lookup table.  I then created two fields in my layout, one for each new field.

For the value you wish to store (ex. Plant_TSN):
Make the corresponding layout field a dropdown and include the show/hide arrow.  Edit the value list you will populate the dropdown with to show the second (reader friendly) column but store the first column value.  In the layout shrink the field to only show the arrow.

For the field you wish the user to see (ex. Plant_SciName):
make the other layout field a Edit Box and prevent field entry in either Browse or Find mode.  But it up against the dropdown arrow created in the previous step to make what looks like one field.

Finally, back in the first field (arrow-only drop down) write a script to push the user friendly number (Plant_SciName) to the edit box when the user-ugly (Plant_TSN) value is picked in the drop down.  I used the OnObjectSave script trigger of the dropdown formatted field.  Script should be something along the lines of 1)  Freeze window, 2) Go to Related Record (based on relationship in lookup table 3) Set Field (i.e. the edit box) and 4) GotoLayout[original] to offset the Freeze.

Probably not an entirely clear explanation, but I bet you will get it on your third read through!  I would have posted a screenshot, but I apparently need 10 "reputation points".

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to type this.  Enough time has passed that I don't remember my exact solution, but this sounds roughly similar to what I did.  A kludge, at best, but it worked well enough and the client seems satisfied.